# Cannot connect with online arduino editor but I can with Arduino IDE to an Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

As the title says I have a Nano with CH340G and 168 that connects properly to Arduino IDE but not to Arduino online editor, it does not detect the board "Error uploading, check if the board is available"

What can I do?

**EDIT**: The IDE online I am using is https://create.arduino.cc/ I am using the same computer and exactly the same board model in both IDEs (both of them have the same options available so both of them should be in the same version)

**EDIT 2**: I can connect correctly from the online IDE to an Arduino UNO. The problem is just with the Nano.

Comment: Which exact online editor? I know several.

Comment: Does the browser run on the same computer as the IDE? Did you select the right board in the Online Editor? Nano comes with a new and an old version of it's firmware. Did you select the same firmware in the IDE and the Online Editor? Have you configured your browser to not connect to external periphery like COM ports?

Comment: @FilipFranik:  added information requested

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer:  added information requested